# dotnet core F# console proj. How to load/open a module?

Tags: module, f#, .net-core, console, project

RaceConditionTest.fs

```
namespace FConsole
module RaceConditionTest = 
   let test x =
       ...
```

Program.fs

```
open System
open FConsole
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    RaceConditionTest.test 1000
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Then I run my console app (linux)

```
$ dotnet run
```

**error** FS0039: The namespace or module 'FConsole' is not defined.

There is only one **test** method in **RaceConditionTest.fs**

Is the order of files the problem? if so, How do I indicate the order of *.fs files?

Comment: the order is specified in .fsproj file in the project

Comment: @boran you are right my file.csproj has this <ItemGroup /> secion I only added my file before program. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @boran suggested in his comments there is this FConsoleProject.fsproj

I just added my file before Program.fs

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="RaceConditionTest.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
</ItemGroup>
```